# Macromedia Flash Desktop API / EXE bundler

Tags: identify-this-software

Sorry if this is *too* recent, but back when I was first getting into programming in ~2002-2004, there was some Flash/SWF-to-EXE tool that provided ActionScript bindings to Windows desktop APIs. Does anyone know what that tool might have been called?

I would have used it with Macromedia Flash MX 2004 or maybe Macromedia Flash 8

Google-ing has been fruitless thanks to the recent death of Flash.

Comment: Given the recent death and entombment of Flash, I would say that this is now definitely retro! I also remember some encapsulation tool that put a wrapper around a Flash 'movie' and produced a Windows exe. In fact, I continue to use many of these files in my day job, as their Flash equivalents no longer run.

Comment: I know it was possible to export to those flash projectors with embedded movies from inside the Flash authoring environment way back in the Macromedia days, but I'm not familiar with how it would be accomplished otherwise.

Comment: This was 15 years ago, so my memory is hazy... I definitely remember it being an external / third-party tool. It somehow let me interface with the OS in a way that standard Flash did not allow.

Comment: @MarkWilliams I don't think "death" necessarily means "retro". For example Office 2013 is dead (I hope) but not retro, and Amiga is not dead but is Retro. I am not sure about Flash.

Comment: there where small standalone win32 player: `flashplayer.exe`  out there which might be used for this just by adding/linking it and your swf file into single executable (resources) and calling it with argument from there .... but that is just my wild guess

Comment: I just found it on my HDD .. its [SAFlashPlayer.exe](https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/saflashplayer-exe/) ~1MByte executable in help it claims `MacroMedia Flash player 7`

Comment: The flash executable files I am using were made in 2002, so use of that tool must have preceded that date.

Comment: @OmarL - I still have family members that use Office 2010. Even it isn't dead -- it just got a security update last week.

Comment: It may not quite fit the "retro" part, but there is an active project called Ruffle that re-implements Flash using Rust and Web Assembly. I used it the other day to play [Samorost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samorost). So if the question is asked for practical purposes similar to mine - revival of old Flash media - then check out their [site](https://ruffle.rs/). It works on Linux, as well as macOS and Windows, can be installed as a browser add-on, or hosted as a web assembly blob on your website.

Answer (score 2):

NativeWindow - Adobe ActionScript® 3 (AS3)

Flash EXE Builder By IncrediTools

Adobe Flash Builder

SWF2EXE Converter by ApecSoft Inc.

VaySoft SWF to EXE Converter Pro

A-PDF Flash Package Builder

These were the only ones that fits to your description, found on Internet. I'm not sure if you meant them.

Comment: There's also Macromedia^W Adobe^W Apache Flex